# How to know the reason a login attempt failed inside the OnLoginError event handler?

Tags: asp.net, membership, login-control

**OnLoginError** event is where to handle login errors. However, I've noticed that the argument of the handler is of **EventArgs**, which doesn't contain any information.

If a login fails, I'd like to know the reason. How do I get the reason a login failed using

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there is no way to know that without possibly querying the underlying store.

This is because the login control internally uses the membership provider and the provider's validation method returns just `bool` with no detailed information on the reason of failed attempt.

Comment: Make sense. Thank you.